# Why are the integers in the array negative after reversing the array and reversing back to the original array?

Tags: c++, arrays, unit-testing, pointers

```
void reverseArray(int arrayLength, int sequence[]){
    int temparr[arrayLength];
    int *pointStart = sequence;
    int *pointEnd = sequence + arrayLength - 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){
        temparr[i] = *pointEnd - i;  
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){
        sequence[i] = temparr[i];
    }

}

void printArray(int arrayLength, int sequence[]){
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++, sequence++){
        std::cout << *sequence << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}




int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    const int num = 50;
    int arr[num]; 

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
      arr[i] = i;
    }

    reverseArray(num, arr);
    std::cout << "Printing reverse array...\n";
    printArray(num, arr);
    reverseArray(num, arr);
    std::cout << "Printing reverse of the reverse array...\n";
    printArray(num, arr);
    ASSERT_EQ(0, arr[0]);
    ASSERT_EQ(24, arr[24]);
    ASSERT_EQ(49, arr[49]);

    return 0;
}
```

I am able to reverse the array, but when I put the "reversed" array back into the function, it seems to be of negative elements. I am not sure where this happens... Anything will help! The unit testing isn't the problem, but it is a part of the code.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkfBC.png

Comment: First question, are you doing it for college/school purposes and you HAVE TO use raw c style array?

Comment: You need to change this line: `temparr[i] = *pointEnd - i ;` to this:  ` `temparr[i] = *( pointEnd - i );  `

Comment: Unrelated: [std::reverse](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)

Comment: @user4581301 Yeah, he probably also shouldn't be using `VLA`'s either.

Comment: If `std::reverse` is disallowed by the assignment, consider using a loop that swaps items from both ends, and then moves toward the middle, swapping as is goes. When the program hits the middle of the array, everything's been swapped and you're done.

Comment: @MichałTurek This is for class and for C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bug with this line:

```
temparr[i] = *pointEnd - i;
```

Here you are dereferencing the `pointEnd` pointer and subtracting `i` from the resulting integer.

What you meant to write is:

```
temparr[i] = *( pointEnd - i );
```

Here you are subtracting `i` from the `pointEnd` pointer, then dereferencing.

That being said, instead of doing confusing pointer arithmetic why not do something like this instead:

```
temparr[ i ] = sequence[ arrayLength - i ];
```

Comment: Or just `temparr[i] = *pointend--;`. (Alternatively, `temparr[i] = *--pointend;` with an appropriate adjustment to the initial value for `pointend`.)

Comment: Crazy fast feedback. The "assignment" for class requires this pointer method. Thank you for the help! Interesting fix...

Comment: @ConnorRonnoc If my answer was able to fix your issue make sure to mark it as accepted.